HDRI does not appear in its complete form

The full image is this at the bottom.

I have no idea why this happens.
This happened even though I created a new file, didn't change anything, and applied the background. Why did this phenomenon happen?

These are the world settings. I didn't change from first setting


How did you "apply" the background? Please show the settings of your world background instead of the render settings.

@GordonBrinkmann https://i.sstatic.net/oTj6D6WA.png
Thank you for your inspection

See how easy it is to find a solution if you provide the necessary details? When asking about the world background, post information about your world background.

You are using an Image Texture node with Flat projection. For the world background you need an Environment Texture node set to Equirectangular in most cases or maybe Mirror Ball - but most downloadable HDRIs use equirectangular mapping and yours too. These projection options do not exist in the Image Texture node.


You are supposed to use an Environment Texture node for world backgrounds. Using an Image Texture node will not map properly.
